# Multiply every chosen row by some value, then sum everything in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, which looks like that:

[image]

I want to calculate the overall price for tickets for 100 adults and 20 childs. I don't know how to add multiple WHEREs to pick the right row for calculations. So far I have something like that

```
SELECT
  Fee * 100 AS adult,
  Fee * 20  AS child,
  sum(*)
FROM fees
WHERE adult.Type = 'adult' AND adult.Clubname = 'aquapark'
WHERE child.Type = 'child' AND child.Clubname = 'aquapark';
```

I want the output to be 110 000 in this case.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question give us an example of what you expect the output to look like?  Also, when you say "single query", does that allow for subqueries?

Comment: I've edited the question with expected value returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT sum(CASE type
             WHEN 'adult' THEN
               fee * 200
             WHEN 'Child' THEN
               fee * 50
             ELSE 
               0
           END)
       FROM fees
       WHERE clubname = 'aquapark';
```

Comment: You could also factor the case statement to just be the fee ratio.  For example `SUM(CASE type WHEN 'adult' THEN 200 WHEN 'Child' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END) * fee`

Comment: Neat! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: In your suggestion, `fee` is not an argument to an aggregation function or in a `GROUP BY` clause. It might work on old MySQL versions or with a loose configuration but might as well produce unexpected results. And it isn't very portable to any DBMS more sane in this respect (which is almost all).

Comment: I think that was a typo on my part, it should have had the closing parentheses *after* `fee` like this: `SUM(CASE type WHEN 'adult' THEN 200 WHEN 'Child' THEN 50 ELSE 0 END * fee)`

Comment: @Mr.Llama: Alright, like that it makes sense and that's a nice simplification!

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) totalAmount
    FROM
        ( 
            select sum(fees.fee * 200) totalAmount from fees where fees.Type = 'adult' AND fees.Clubname = 'aquapark'
            UNION ALL
            select sum(fees.fee * 50) totalAmount from fees where fees.Type = 'child' AND fees.Clubname = 'aquapark'
        ) s
```

The above query is doing a sum of separate queries for adult and child assuming that you want results for a specific club name and also that your column names and table names are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
SUM(fee)
WHERE Type IN ('child', 'adult')
GROUP BY(Clubname, Type)
```

to get what you want.